# JQuery code not executing in notepad++

Tags: jquery, notepad++

[image]What is wrong with this code?Why isn't it working?Is there anything wrong or missing?I am using notepad++.

```
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>First jquery page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="one">This text should change.</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#one').html = "Changed";
    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is the jquery file in the same folder as your html file?

Comment: `.html` is a function. Writing `.html = 'something'` replaces the function with the string "something", hence, you won't be able to use the function anymore! OO' Don't worry, replace `.html = "Changed"` with `.html("Changed")`, and everything should be fine :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using jquery to change text. so you should use as follow:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>First jquery page</title>
```

```
</head>

<body>
<div id="one">This text should change.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#one').html ("Changed");
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```